# Is a 1 GB graphics card is enough for big Figma design?

Tags: figma

I have a graphics card with 256 MB internal and not dedicated. I want to buy a dedicated 1 GB graphics card. Is it good enough for a big Figma design?

Like: [This](https://www.figma.com/file/wfTKJCjTC7nwU5tUhEc3hZ/space-tourism-website?node-id=0%3A1).
This design, when I add an image to it, works very slowly. Is a 1 GB graphics card good enough?

Comment: Hardware questions are off topic. --- However, practically **any** computer sold today will be fine with 95% of all design software. The only time one really needs to be concerned about more/boosted performance is if doing a great deal of 3D rendering or video editing. Browser-based software relies a great deal on the **browser** and internet connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figma is a browser in miniature, so it requires more computer resources in terms of RAM than a graphics card.

Depending on your situation, if you add another graphics card, but your RAM remains the same, it is not a guarantee that you will be able to work comfortably.

Answer (score -1):

Like the guys above said, Figma doesn't really use a graphics card. It's supposed to run in browser and be used on tablets so it's pretty well optimized in that regard.
Get more RAM instead.
I wrote an article about the [recommended system requirements](https://8designers.com/blog/can-my-laptop-run-figma#answer) for the desktop app:

- Operating System: Windows 7 SP1 or later, macOS 10.13 or later
- Processor: 2GHz Intel Core 2 Duo or AMD Athlon 64 X2 processor
- **Memory: 4 GB RAM**
- Storage: 500MB of available disk space
- Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000 or later, AMD Radeon HD 7000 or later, or an Nvidia GeForce 500 series graphics card or later
- Network: Broadband internet connection

Disclaimer: I own the site linked.